# Concatenar array de checkboxes selecionados para usar como filtro de busca

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma busca com diversos checkboxes que podem ser selecionados e adicionados dinamicamente pelo usuário. Como não sei a quantidade, estava pensando em fazer o seguinte: percorrer todos eles e ir concatenando com `AND` e usar isso na condição lá na busca.

O problema é que do jeito que fiz acaba ficando um `AND` sozinho no final da busca. Segue meu código:

```
$Busca = $_POST['txtbusca'];
$arrayFiltro = $_POST['chkDisciplina'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayFiltro); $i++) { 
    echo $arrayFiltro[$i]. "AND";
}
```

Existe uma maneira melhor?

Comment: Poste sua SQL que deve ser gerada com esse filtro de busca?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função [**`implode()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) foi feita para isso:

```
$separador = ' AND ';
$array = array( 'nome', 'email', 'fone' );
$string = implode( $separador, $array );
var_dump( $string );
```

Resulta em:

> string(28) "nome AND email AND fone"

Comment: E, pra complementar, se preferir pode usar também o join()[http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php], que é um apelido para o implode();

Comment: O link que pus no comentário acima ficou com o "]" no link, então segue sem: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php

Comment: @LeoFelipe, confira a [formatação de comentários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Vlw @brasofilo. Nas próximas estarão com marcação correta!

Answer (score 1):

Meio que gambiarra, mas tenta isso, você verifica, caso a variável de controle $i seja menor que o tamanho do array, você pode ir adicionando o AND no final, caso a variável seja igual ao tamanho do vetor, significa que é o último elemento, então não precisa de AND, então cai dentro do else.

```
$Busca = $_POST['txtbusca'];
$arrayFiltro = $_POST['chkDisciplina'];
$sql = "SELECT * suatabelela WHERE = ";
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayFiltro); $i++) { 
    if($i<count($arrayFiltro) {
          $sqlAND .= $arrayFiltro[$i]. "AND";
    } else {
    $sqlAND .= $arrayFiltro[$i];
    }
}
```